# How to make a string in swift include subscript letters

Tags: ios, swift

I have a string and I want it to have subscript letters below it, for example

[image]

I have not been able to find an example in swift which clearly shows/explains how to do this.

Answer (score 3):

In Swift, a String can contain any unicode character. Go to Edit -> Emoji & Symbols in Xcode to insert the subscript into the X₂.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using an `NSAttributedString` and setting a different `font` and [`baselineOffset`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsattributedstringkey/1526427-baselineoffset) to that section of the string.

A baseline offset will move that section of the string up and down.

Answer (score 0):

Use `NSAttributedString` and its mutable subclass `NSMutableAttributedString`:

```
func makeSubscript(baseString: String, subscriptString: String, attributes: [NSAttributedStringKey: Any] = [:]) -> NSAttributedString {
    // Merge the default attributes with those provided by the user
    let attributes: [NSAttributedStringKey: Any] = [
        .font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 14)
    ].merging(attributes) { $1 }

    // Configure the attributes for subscript
    let font = attributes[.font] as! UIFont
    let baselineOffset = NSNumber(value: -Double(font.pointSize) * 0.15)
    let subscriptAttributes: [NSAttributedStringKey: Any] = [
        .font: font.withSize(font.pointSize * 0.5),
        .baselineOffset: baselineOffset
    ].merging(attributes) { $0 }

    let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: baseString, attributes: attributes)
    attributedString.append(NSAttributedString(string: subscriptString, attributes: subscriptAttributes))

    return attributedString
}
```

Result:

```
makeSubscript(baseString: "x", subscriptString: "2")
```

[image: x_2]

```
makeSubscript(baseString: "x", subscriptString: "20", attributes: [.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 100), .foregroundColor: UIColor.blue])
```

[image: x_20]

You can assign the result to the `label.attributedText` property.

---

The `Dictionary.merge()` function requires a bit of explanation here. Let's say you have two dictionaries:

```
let dictA = ["firstName": "John", "lastName": "Smith"]
let dictB = ["lastName": "Willy", "nickname": "Jack"]
```

`merge` combines the two dictionaries and decide which value take priority if a key is present in both dictionaries:

```
let dictC = dictA.merging(dictB) { valueInA, valueInB in valueInA }
// ["firstName": "John", "lastName": "Smith", "nickname": "Jack"]

let dictD = dictA.merging(dictB) { valueInA, valueInB in valueInB }
// ["firstName": "John", "lastName": "Willy", "nickname": "Jack"]
```